# Login validation error

Tags: django, authentication, django-forms, django-views, django-login

I'm a Django newbie.

My login page requires just "username" and "password" and if they are left blank or filled in incorrectly, I'd like to **raise ValidationError**. I created codes, but it just raises

> "KeyError at /login/" and  "UnboundLocalError at /login/ :local
>   variable 'context' referenced before assignment"

How can I fix my codes?

views.py

```
def LoginRequest(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username=form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            uasite1= authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if uasite1 is not None:
                login(request, uasite1)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
            else:
                return render_to_response('login.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return render_to_response('login.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        context ={ 'form' : form}
        return render_to_response('login.html',{'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

form.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label = (u'User Name'))
    password = forms.CharField(label = (u'Password'),widget = forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))

    def clean_username(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if not data:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please Enter Username.")
        return data

    def clean_password(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['password']
        if not data:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please Enter Password.")
        return data

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email or Password is incorrect.")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing template...

```
from django import template

context_instance=template.RequestContext(request)
```

And..
There is not reference to context used here....

```
return render_to_response('login.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I'm sorry context → {'form' : form}. But now I cannot login and if I leave "username" or "password" blank or both blank, the "KeyError at /login/
'username(password)'" occurred. Maybe forms.py has some problems?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using Django login in the first place?

Comment: I don't think so. What is Django login? I just consulted this website to make my login page. http://hackedexistence.com/project/django/video7-userauthentication-2.html

Comment: Django provides User authentication which includes passwodd hashing. Take a look in to this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Comment: If you are done with issues on this question. Please close it by marking it as answered.